# Bottom sheet is overlapping focussed TextFormField when keyboard is open

Tags: flutter, dart, bottom-sheet

I am currently doing my first Flutter project and am having quite some trouble finding things out.
One of the problems I have been having for days now is that I cannot see my focussed TextFormField when I open the keyboard in one specific view.

I recently discovered that Flutter actually tries to put the focussed TextFormField right above my keyboard, but that my bottomSheet is in the way. See pictures below:
[image: This is my form. I will now click on the TextFormField which says 'F.E. Eindhoven']
[image: As you can see, the bottomSheet is overlapping the focussed TextFormField]

And see below the code for my UI:

```
return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: const [
              Text(
                'Capture moment',
              ),
              Text(
                'Tell me what happened.',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 18),
              ),
            ])),
        body: CustomScrollView(slivers: [
          SliverFillRemaining(
              hasScrollBody: false,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Give your moment a name',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 12),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 6),
                          SizedBox(
                              width: 340,
                              child: TextFormField(
                                onChanged: (value) => manager.setName(value),
                                initialValue: manager.name,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                                    hintText: 'F.e. meeting at work'),
                              )),
                          SizedBox(height: 12),
                          Text('Where did it happen?',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 12)),
                          SizedBox(height: 6),
                          SizedBox(
                              width: 340,
                              child: TextFormField(
                                onChanged: (value) =>
                                    manager.setLocation(value),
                                initialValue: manager.location,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: 'F.e. Eindhoven',
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                                ),
                              )),
                          SizedBox(height: 12),
                          Text('Add an icon to your moment',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 12)),
                          SizedBox(height: 6),
                          SizedBox(
                              width: 340,
                              child: TextFormField(
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: 'Search',
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                                ),
                              )),
                          SizedBox(height: 12),
                          Text('When did this happen?',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 12)),
                          SizedBox(height: 6),
                          SizedBox(
                              width: 340,
                              child: Row(children: [
                                Text('Start'),
                                Spacer(),
                                DateTimeSelector(
                                  initialValue: manager.startDate,
                                  useTime: true,
                                  onChanged: (value) =>
                                      manager.setStartDate(value!),
                                )
                              ])),
                          SizedBox(height: 12),
                          SizedBox(
                              width: 340,
                              child: Row(children: [
                                Text('End'),
                                Spacer(),
                                DateTimeSelector(
                                  initialValue: manager.endDate,
                                  useTime: true,
                                  onChanged: (value) =>
                                      manager.setEndDate(value!),
                                )
                              ])),
                        ],
                      )),
                ],
              ))
        ]),
        bottomSheet: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 340,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: ((context) =>
                            const AddFeelingToMomentScreen()))),
              },
              child: const Text('Next'),
            ),
          ),
        ));
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you try `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh On what element exactly?

Comment: oh my bad, it is a scaffold parameter , `Scaffold(resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,`

Comment: While this does hide the bottomSheet when my keyboard is open, it poses another problem: The third TextFormField (which says 'Search') is still overlapped by the keyboard when selected. The UI doesn't shrink to fit it above the keyboard. Any ideas>?

Comment: Sorry not sure, also your snippet using CustomscrollView, try to use  sliverList

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ListView instead of Column at the start of scaffold body parameter